# Playing video from remote server using url in html

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, video

It's for my college contest, my task is:

1. To play mp4 video in html or my website.
2. URL is provided by user it can google docs or mega or any type of link sourcing mp4 file.
3. My website should take user url and upon play the video should play
4. File can be >=1GB
5. it can be from ftp server ex ftp://10.x.x.x/demo.mp4

I tried

1. I tried using video.js and some of other js players.
2. Upon inspect element i saw 206 partial content
3. I tried searching the code 206 upon which i saw some answers where people said to use file as chunks instead of single blob.(i dont
   know how)

My coding level is beginner
I have basic knowledge about js , python flask and html
python flask answer is also appreciated.
Thank you
i dont know how to stackoverflow :(

Comment: FTP isn't going to work.  Serve it with HTTP, and you can use a simple `<video>` tag and be done with it.

Comment: @Brad i tried http but same 206 partial content in inspect file is of 1gb

Comment: 206 is what's supposed to happen.  The browser only requests part of the file at a time.  The server sends that part.  The browser will request more when it's time to play that part.

Comment: @Brad that is where upon searching i found some reference of solution like accepting range in headers, and other was requesting file as chunks .
The video doesn't play i just loads endlessly.